# Generalized Schanuel Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

This is on page 128, ex 3.15, of Rotman's AIHA,

> (Schanuel) Let $B$ be a left $R$-module over some ring $R$ consider two exact sequences,
> $$ 0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow P_n \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0 $$
> $$ 0 \rightarrow K' \rightarrow P'_n \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0 $$
> where $P_*, P'_*$ are projectives, prove that
> $$ K \oplus P'_n \oplus P_{n-1} \oplus \cdots \cong K' \oplus P_n \oplus P'_{n-1} \oplus \cdots $$

I could not really apply the usuall Schanuel's lemma, any hint?

Comment: Break your long exact sequences into short exact sequences...

Comment: Actually, I am in fact confused at how the $\cdots $ end? since as you suggested, i think i can prove if the $\cdots $ end as 
$$ K \oplus P'_n \oplus P_{n-1} \oplus P'_{n-1} \oplus P_{n-2} \oplus P'_{n-2} \cdots $$

Comment: A slightly stronger form (which I find more useful) is that the chain complexes: $$ P_n\oplus P \rightarrow P_{n-1}\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow P_0 $$ and 
 $$ P'_n \oplus P' \rightarrow P_{n-1}'\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow P_0' $$ are chain homotopy equivalent, with respect to the identity on $B$.  Here $$P= P'_n \oplus P_{n-1} \oplus \cdots$$ and $$P'= P_n \oplus P'_{n-1} \oplus \cdots $$   with the first differentials restricting to $0$ on $P,P'$ respectively.  The homotopy equivalence is given explicitly in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ecca/bf6206e5f1736b77491cffdf6da67541f220.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I found the following proof in *Lectures on Modules and Rings* by T. Y. Lam.

We do an induction on $n$. Assume the claim is true for $n-1$. Write $f$ and $g$ for the arrows $P_{0}\to B$ and $Q_{0}\to B$.
Applying the usual version of Schanuel's lemma to the sequences
\begin{gather*}
0\to\ker f\to P_{0}\to B\to0,\\
0\to\ker g\to Q_{0}\to B\to0,
\end{gather*}
we deduce that $\ker g\oplus P_{0}\cong\ker f\oplus Q_{0}$. Now the induction hypothesis applies to the sequences
\begin{gather*}
0\to K\to P_{n}\to\dots\to P_{2}\to P_{1}\oplus Q_{0}\to\ker f\oplus Q_{0}\to0,\\
0\to K'\to Q_{n}\to\dots\to Q_{2}\to Q_{1}\oplus P_{0}\to\ker g\oplus P_{0}\to0.
\end{gather*}